# How to get a filtered list from an existing list

Tags: c#, .net-core, blazor-webassembly

This project is a .NET Core 6 Blazor PWA hosted and using the shared-"Heading"-model, server-repository, server-controller and client-service tasks.

On the client-side, this filtering does NOT work and am very confused why it does not work.

The `Heading` model class contains fields for

```
int UID_HEADING
int UID_CUSTOMER
string TXT_NAME
boolean BOOL_IS_ACTIVE 
int INT_SORT_ORDER
```

The `IEnumerable Heading _AllHeadings` list contains 5 records.

In the UI, there is a dropdown showing the CUSTOMERS (1 to 23).

I need to filter the `_AllHeadings` based on the customer's `pUID_CUSTOMER` and I tried this:

```
_FilteredHeadings = _AllHeadings
    .Where(c => (c.UID_CUSTOMER == pUID_CUSTOMER) 
             && (c.BOOL_IS_ACTIVE == bIsActive))
    .OrderBy(e => e.INT_SORT_ORDER)
    .ToList();
```

However, the `_FilteredHeadings` only contains ONE record, even though there should be a subset of the complete list of `_AllHeadings`.

I am very confused as to why this lambda code does not do what I think it should do.

I am not much experienced in Linq and lambda code.

BTW -- if I change the development-code to

```
_FilteredHeadings = _AllHeadings;
```

Then all of the records appear -- for all customers.

Your answers, comments and questions are welcome.

Thanks.

Comment: Are you sure that your data contains more than one result that meets both those conditions?

Comment: Yes...One customer has all five Heading(s).  thx.

Comment: But is it the customer id that you are filtering on? Please provide a [minimal reproducible example](https://stackoverflow.com/help/minimal-reproducible-example). On the face of it, your code should work

Comment: Yes the _AllHeadings model contains a UID_CUSTOMER and the UI-selected value is pUID_Customer.  Business wise, each customer can have it's own Heading(s).  This is part of the CRUD for Headings by the administrator.

Comment: That doesn't answer my point. Please give an MRE

Comment: Do you want to see the customer-data and the heading data?

Comment: Sidenote: This looks like an incorrect order: `.OrderBy(e => e.INT_SORT_ORDER.ToString())`. Because you sacrifice a correct numeric ordering against alphanumeric(so 11 comes before 2)

Comment: Thank you, Tim...I am aware of your astute catch on the ToString.  but for now, there are only 5-records in total.  I was NOT sure if the UI part of the blazor code would tolerate ordering by and INTEGER field.  I have been struggling with this for days. now and finally came to other experts for Linq, lambda and Blazor.   -- I will change the source code...thx.

Comment: To @Jonathan Willcock... Please change your "comment" to an "answer" and I will give you credit for helping me solve this problem.  In looking for MRE I revisited the DataBase tables and found that the "Heading" table did NOT contain the currect data for the UID_CUSTOMER field -- THUS -- only one record was returned no matter which customer was selected from the UI-dropdown.  I edited the table with the "correct" UID_CUSTOMER values. The lambda filtering is now showing the correct data on the UI.  Thank you ALL SO much who replied in this post.  You all are very smart!!!!